# The site is in a subdomain, but I get the wrong file path and a "require_once(): Failed opening required..." error

Tags: 7, migrations

I have inherited a half ready development site, which I have to finish for the client. First I tried to backup and move to an other location, so I am sure that I can migrate the whole site. I moved the code to a subdirectory of one of the sites I manage, created a database and imported it from the old location. I also updated the settings.php with the proper database information. I tried to reach the site with "sitedomain.com/cicad" (cicad is the subdirectory name) and I get this error message.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/clients/*hashthag*/web-arvr/sites/all/themes/cicad/templates/_menu-header-block.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php7.0/lib/php') in /home/clients/*hashthag*/web-arvr/cicad/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 2

The problem is that the proper path should start with /home/clients/*hashthag*/web-arvr/**cicad**/sites/. It doesn't include the SENTI subdirectory name in this path.

I have already tried:

- Setting *RewriteBase /cicad*
- Setting *DocumentRoot /home/clients/_hashtag_/web-arvr/cicad*
- Setting $base_url to "domainname.com/cicad"
- Clearing the cache by Empty every cache_* table in the database.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may not use a subdirectory, but a subdomain instead, to have the site on the domain root (subdomains are often free and easy to configure in your hosting panel). This will prevent you from a lot of trouble when migrating from and to production.

The site is probably deducing paths from the drupal base path, which is incorrectly calculated in your setup (subdirectory), you will loose less time setting a "root domain installation" than looking for the errors in this site you don't know how to handle (yet).

The site is also probably hiding a lot of surprises, here the error comes from the "PHP" module, which should not happen on admin. There is probably some PHP inside blocks, which is not a good news.

Comment: Yeah, I was also thinking about that. My next try will be that this night.